# error Converting PDF to PNG - Python 3.6 and GhostScript

Tags: pdf, png, ghostscript, python-3.6, wand

I have much trouble to have a code to convert pdf file to png on python 3.6, windows 10.

I know what you are going to say  : **google it !**

But barely everything I've found was on **python 2.7**. And some packages haven't been updated.

What I've seen so far it's that the best way to do it is using **Wand**, right ? (I have installed **ImageMagick** before )

```
from wand.image import Image
# Converting first page into JPG
with Image(filename='0.pdf') as img:
    img.save(filename="/temp.jpg")
# Resizing this image
```

Here was my second error :

```
wand.exceptions.DelegateError: PDFDelegateFailed 
`The system cannot find the file specified.' @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/809
```

So i read i need **ghostscript**. I installed it. But the package is for python 2.7 and it doesn't work. I found **python3-ghostscript** 0.5.0. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python3-ghostscript/0.5.0

New error :

```
RuntimeError: Can not find Ghostscript DLL in registry
```

So here I needed to install Ghostscript 9 :
https://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html

---

First of all it's not a GPL license ... That's not even a package but a program. I don't know how I can use it in my futures python codes...

---

and there is still an error :

```
RuntimeError: Can not find Ghostscript DLL in registry
```

and i can't find anything for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ghostscript is licensed under the AGPL, the licence can be found in /Program Files (x86)/gs/gs9.21/doc if you want sources then they are available from the Ghostscript Git [repository](http://git.ghostscript.com/?p=ghostpdl.git;a=summary). Note I'm assuming you are running on Windows since you refer to the Registry.

If you install the prebuilt binary then it will create an entry in the Windows Registry, I assume that's what your Python code is looking for but I can't be sure. You should make sure you install the correct word size (32 or 64) version required by Python, if it cares.

You can, of course, simply run Ghostscript to render a PDF file and produce PNG output.

```
gswin32c -sDEVICE=png16m -sOutputFile=out%d.png input.pdf
```

This will create one file per page of the input PDF file, use gswin64c for the 64-bit version...

You can alter the resolution of the output with the `-r` switch, eg `-r300`

I presume you can simply fork a process from Python. Otherwise you'll have to get someone to tell you what the Python script is looking for in the Registry. Perhaps its looking for a specific version of Ghostscript, or the 32-bit version or something.